# TestNg Annotation Syntax

Tags: java, annotations, testng, testng-dataprovider

I started learning TestNG but i got stuck so i need little help related to syntax
I have already using annotation dataProvider

```
@Test(dataProvider="getdata")
public void testCase02(String text1,String text2){
    System.out.println("I m in second testcase");
    System.out.println(text1);`
    System.out.println(text2);
}
```

But i also want to use annotation `(groups="group")` so can anyone help me out for syntax to use both annotation together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To mark a test method to belong to a group, you need to do is specify the `groups` attribute of the `Test`

```
@Test(dataProvider="getdata", groups = {"groupName"})
public void testCase02(String text1,String text2) {
```

There is a detailed documentation from [testng](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) around it.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some documents or sites to crate framework on testNG

Comment: @shubhambansal Already linked there documentation page. You can go ahead and use it to create framework as well.

Comment: @shubhambansal If this helps, could you please accept it as an answer so that its useful for any future readers.